# Simultaneous READ COMMITTED transactions updates a select for update columns

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, transaction

I have a READ COMMITTED transaction in which I am trying to update a row and increment a column value till it reaches a bucket value contained in another column. Please see the code below

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `testproc`()
BEGIN
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
    BEGIN
    ROLLBACK;
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE 'ERR0R' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'An error has occurred, operation rollbacked and the stored procedure was terminated' ;
    END;

SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED;

--- SOME LOGIC HERE ---
START TRANSACTION;
IF(SELECT IF(CurrentSize<BucketSize,TRUE,FALSE) FROM TestTable WHERE id = someId)
THEN
--- SOME INSERTIONS HERE ---
IF(SELECT IF(CurrentSize=BucketSize-1,TRUE,FALSE) FROM TestTable WHERE id = someId FOR UPDATE)
THEN
UPDATE TestTable SET CurrentSize = CurrentSize+1 WHERE id = someId;
--- SOME LOGIC HERE ---
ELSE
UPDATE TestTable SET CurrentSize = CurrentSize+1 WHERE id = someId;
END IF;

--- BELOW IS ADDED AS A EXTRA PRECAUTION ---
IF((SELECT COUNT(1) FROM TestTable WHERE CurrentSize > BucketSize AND id = someId) > 0)
THEN
ROLLBACK;
END IF;
END IF;
END
```

This works fine under normal load. But when we reach a high traffic I don't know for what reason the above logic fails and The CurrentSize column reaches a greater value than BucketSize.

It would be great if someone could help me with the same.

Comment: Do you call the `testproc` in a loop? In a high concurrency system if you have threads that are updating a counter, you must insert some kind of barrier when the counter reach the value you want. Maybe you can use `get_lock()` mysql function. Could you tell more about what you are trying to do?

Comment: Hi @Giovanni Thanks for the comment. I am not running the above proc in a loop. I believe SELECT .. FOR UPDATE does a similar thing to get_lock() (correct me if I am wrong here). Basically I am trying to maintain a bucket which when fills creates a new bucket. I have just shown the simple logic of incrementing counter which should halt on reaching its max value. But it fails under high concurrency.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to modify the `testproc` in the following way. I have tryed to be more simple as possible:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `testproc`()
BEGIN    
  START TRANSACTION;
  select 'try to acquire lock';
  SELECT CurrentSize, BucketSize into @cursize, @bucketsize 
  FROM TestTable WHERE id = 1 FOR UPDATE;
  select 'acquired lock';  -- only one thread is permitted here
  select sleep(1);  -- some work here
  IF @cursize < @bucketsize THEN
    select concat('CurrentSize < BucketSize (', @cursize, '<', @bucketsize, ')');
    UPDATE TestTable SET CurrentSize = CurrentSize+1 WHERE id = 1;
  ELSE
    select concat('CurrentSize >= BucketSize (', @cursize, '>', @bucketsize, ')');
  END IF;
  COMMIT;  
  select 'lock released';
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

The main point is: only one thread can get a lock on the row. Only after the lock is acquired, it can update the counter. (You can use double check design pattern for performance reason but it is a little more complex). You don't need to read uncommited transactions.

To get an insight, I have called `testproc` from two or more mysql clients in a loop. So I have defined a loop:

```
create table TestTable( id int primary key, CurrentSize int, BucketSize int ) engine=innodb;
insert into TestTable (id, CurrentSize, BucketSize) values (1, 1, 5);

delimiter $$
create procedure test_loop()
begin
   declare i int default 30;
   while i >0 do
     call testproc();
     set i = i -1;
   end while;
end $$
delimiter ;
```

I have launched two mysql clients:

```
mysql1> call test_loop();

mysql2> call test_loop();

mysql1> select * from TestTable;
+----+-------------+------------+
| id | CurrentSize | BucketSize |
+----+-------------+------------+
|  1 |           5 |          5 |
+----+-------------+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

You can try to comment out `FOR UPDATE` into the `testproc`:

```
SELECT CurrentSize, BucketSize into @cursize, @bucketsize 
FROM TestTable WHERE id = 1;  -- FOR UPDATE;
```

If you try several times the previous test, you could get 6 into `CurrentSize` column.

```
mysql1> call test_loop();

mysql2> call test_loop();

mysql1> select * from TestTable;
+----+-------------+------------+
| id | CurrentSize | BucketSize |
+----+-------------+------------+
|  1 |           6 |          5 |
+----+-------------+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Hope it is help.

Comment: Hi @Giovanni, Thanks for the effort you put into it but I guess I have found out the issue which was cause of the above behavior. What I didn't show or mention in my question was that I had multiple ROLLBACK in my logic which executed in my SP and I also expected the SP to quit after my ROLLBACK statement. Well I found out that it is not possible without using a label and a LEAVE statement. So now I have added the same to my SP and load tested it but I am still observing the behavior under actual load. Keeping fingers crossed. Thanks alot for the help again.

Comment: @amit1310 - please update the code in your question to indicate the `ROLLBACK` flaw.  Otherwise readers will get confused until the read the fine print here.